# How to reduce the number of delimiters using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed, csv

I have data that is supposed to be 30 columns each row. The export is not perfectly executed and I occasionally get 32 - 50 columns because there are extra tab delimiters in the field's themselves.

I also need to eliminated commas from my thousands with the following sed program.

```
sed '/[0-9],[0-9]./ {s/,//g; }' $oldfile > $newfile
```

So how do I transform the following data eliminating the commas and merging extra deliminator into the last column

here's my sample input:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
James   1,203.33    comment1
Mike    -3,434.09   testing testing 123
Sarah   1,343,342.23    there   here
```

I would like the output to be:

```
Column 1    Column2 Column3
James   1203.33 comment1
Mike    -3434.09    testing_tab_testing_tab_123
Sarah   1343342.23  there_tab_here
```

So in the end I need to delete commas when they appear in a number 
I also want to find rows with more then 3 (or the appropriate number of tabs) and then
replace the tabs after three to *tab* so I can deal with them after I upload them into my database and everything will be in 3 columns.

I was hoping I could do this in `sed` (at which I am a newbie) or awk (I don't know `awk` at all), because `sed` is really fast at processing all this.

Edit: This is what ended up working best for my situation

`sed '/[0-9],[0-9]./ {s/,//g; };s/\t/_tab_/3g' input_file`

first it eliminates all commas between two number. Then it replaces my tabs with "*tab*" after the third occurrence. I'll test it out at work.

My reasoning for not using perl is that my limited knowledge of it leads me to believe it will need to load the document into memory to evaluate it and these documents range from 5gb to 30gb which regular exceeds my computers memory.

I'll let ya'll know if anything goes wrong when I use it at work, but I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: Do you mean to say that each column of data (what `awk` or `perl` call a "field") is 30 characters wide?  each row having 30 columns is different.

Comment: They are supposed to have 30 columns, but there are extra delimiters in the columns sometimes which causes issues when I try to upload them into my database. I'm trying to get rid of them up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part is replacing those tabs. Let's take this in stages.

First we try to replace *every* tab with "_tab_";

```
sed 's/\t/_tab_/g'

Column1_tab_Column2_tab_Column3
James_tab_1,203.33_tab_comment1
Mike_tab_-3,434.09_tab_testing_tab_testing_tab_123
Sarah_tab_1,343,342.23_tab_there_tab_here
```

(Note that the command contains "\t", meaning TAB. Not all versions of sed allow that; you may have to use an actual tab.) Once we have that working, we can try replacing tabs, starting with the third. Some versions of sed allow this:

```
sed 's/\t/_tab_/3g'
```

If your sed doesn't allow that, you may have to resort to replacing the last tab (if there are more than two):

```
sed 's/\(\t.*\t.*\)\t/\1_tab_/'
```

(you may or may not have to escape the parentheses with backslashes, as I've done) and then repeating that operation until it stops doing anything, by means of a conditional jump to a label:

```
sed -e :a -e 's/\(\t.*\t.*\)\t/\1_tab_/;t a'
```

When you have that working one way or the other, removing the commas is relatively simple, you can just add one more clause to the command:

```
... -e 's/\([0-9]\),/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Delete commas when they appear in a number I also want to find rows with more then 3(or the appropriate number of tabs) and then replace the tabs after three to tab

To delete commas when they appear in a number:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+),/\1/g' inputfile
```

To replace three or more tabs with a single tab:

```
sed -E 's/\t{3,}/\t/g' inputfile
```

Or apply both substitutions in a single command:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+),/\1/g;s/\t{3,}/\t/g' inputfile
```

Sample input (here `\t` means tab):

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
James   1,203.33 \t\t\t comment1
Mike    -3,434.09 \t\t testing testing 123
Sarah   1,343,342.23 \t\t\t there   here
```

Output:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
James   1203.33 \t comment1
Mike    -3434.09 \t\t testing testing 123
Sarah   1343342.23 \t there   here
```

---

Edit: To replace `\t` with `_tab_` for 3rd or greater occurrences in a given line you could use perl:

```
perl -pe 's{\t}{++$n >= 3 ? "_tab_" : $&}ge' inputfile
```

Sample input:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
James  \t 1,203.33 \t comment1
Mike  \t  -3,434.09 \t testing\ttesting\t123
Sarah  \t 1,343,342.23 \t there\there
```

Output:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
James  \t 1,203.33 \t comment1
Mike  \t  -3,434.09 \t testing_tab_testing_tab_123
Sarah  \t 1,343,342.23 \t there_tab_here
```

Comment: I understood his tab thing to mean that the first two tabs on a line should be left along and all the tabs after that should be replaced with the literal word tab so that the final column has the remaining text after the number.

Comment: I think you're right, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: That's right in my sample data I need 3 columns separated by tab at the end of the day. I want the tabs replaced with _tab_ so I can query them later and fix them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this awk

```
awk -F'\t' -v nbcol=3 '
 {a=""
 for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
   {if($i~/[-0-9+,\.]*/)
     gsub(",","",$i)
   if(i>nbcol)a=a"_"$i}
 $0=$1 FS $2 FS $3 a
}1' infile.txt
```

---

-F'\t' field separator

nbcol=3 column to merge

a="" string for merging column must be initialized to empty string

for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) operate on each row

if($i~/[-0-9+,.]*/)gsub(",","",$i)

If the field is a number remove each ,

if(i>nbcol)a=a"_"$i}

if the field number is greater than nbcol merge it in string a

$0=$1 FS $2 FS $3 a

at the end of each line regenerate $0 and print the line with 1